# Filtrar rango de 3 meses en SQL

Tags: mysql

Necesito ayuda con una consulta SQL. En particular necesito filtrar los registros de una tabla de pólizas y que se muestren aquellas pólizas que van a vencer de aquí a 3 meses. Obviamente no me vale poner la fecha de dentro de 3 meses a mano, debe calcularla cada día al ejecutar la consulta.

He probado esto, pero estoy usando phpmyadmin (SQL DB) y no funciona el getdate

````
FROM polizas
INNER JOIN tomadores ON polizas.ID_TOMADOR = tomadores.ID_TOM
INNER JOIN aseguradoras ON polizas.ID_ASEG = aseguradoras.ID_ASEG
WHERE polizas.FIN >= getdate() AND polizas.FIN <= DATEADD(mm, 3, GETDATE()) ```

Como comentaba, la línea problemática es la última, pero no sé como hacer que funcione

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias de antemano
````

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Tene en cuenta que phpmyadmin no es una base de datos, solamente es una forma de conectarse a mysql. y SQL DB no es nada conocido, habras querido decir otra cosa?

Comment: Perdón, quería decir MySQL. Por cierto, hay alguna forma de crear una vista de usuario limpia a partir de phpmyadmin? Ya se que uso mysql, pero quizás phpmyadmin me permitiese crear vistas limpias para usuarios normales

Comment: eso seria otra pregunta.. y que seria una vista limpia? a que llamas eso?

Comment: Pues una vista donde el usuario no vea tablas que no debe de ver y que, por ejemplo, tenga un formulario para insertar campos o buscarlos

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. El usuario no deberia entrar a la base de datos.

Comment: Pero entonces, en una empresa, ¿como añaden registros de ventas o consultan ventas pasadas?

Comment: Si te digo la verdad, estoy en prácticas y he hecho la base de datos en phpmyadmin, pero a partir de ahi no se seguir

Comment: Las empresas tienen sistemas desde donde se accede a la base de datos. Se hacen programas (de escritorio, web) para que los usuarios carguen los datos. Los usuarios no saben sql. Ni les importa.

Comment: Vale, pero qué aplicación puedo usar para crear ese front-end?

Comment: Cualquier ide de desarrollo con cualquier lenguaje. No hay un front end especifico para mysql. Podes usar cualquier lenguaje que quieras

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás utilizando la sintaxis de SQL Server y por lo que veo utilizas MySQL, el equivalente a `GETDATE()` en MySQL es `CURDATE()` y el equivalente a la función `DATEADD` es `DATE_ADD`.

Por lo que la línea del `WHERE` problemática quedaría así

```
WHERE polizas.FIN >= CURDATE() AND polizas.FIN <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

Comment: Gracias!! Eres un genio